# use of class template requires template argument list, nested classes

Tags: c++, templates, generics, arraylist, nested-forms

I'm trying to implement by own generic/template ArrayList and I've run into a snag. I know the error comes from not having  somewhere in the argument list but for me I can't figure it out here, I get a different error if I do. For brevity I've removed functions I'm unable to debug until this one is debugged first.

//ArrayList.h//

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T> 
class ArrayList {
private:
    class Node {
        private:
            Node* next;
            Node* prev;
            T* element;
        public:
            Node();
            Node( T* );
            Node( Node* /*new prev*/, T* );
            ~Node();
            void setNext( Node* );
            Node* getNext();
    };
    int size;
    int maxSize;
    int current_index;
    Node* myArrayList;

    Node* curr;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
public:
};
```

Implementation of "Node* getNext();" in my cpp file.

//ArrayList.cpp//

```
#include "arraylist.h"

...

template <class T> 
ArrayList::Node* ArrayList::Node::getNext() {
    return this->next;
}
```

Trying to insert  behind :: hasn't worked very well... Node* becomes undefined if I put  before it.

```
template <class T> 
ArrayList<T>::Node* ArrayList::Node::getNext() {
    return this->next;
}
```

Then I get ";" expected before "*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
template <class T> 
typename ArrayList<T>::Node* ArrayList<T>::Node::getNext()
{
    return this->next;
}
```

Or in C++11 ([Demo](http://ideone.com/MZ9KKX)):

```
template <class T> 
auto ArrayList<T>::Node::getNext() -> Node*
{
    return this->next;
}
```

or just use an in-line definition, which is recommended for simple accessors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your member functions as such :

```
template <class T> 
typename ArrayList<T>::Node* ArrayList<T>::Node::getNext() {
    return this->next;
}
```

Comment: `Node` is a dependent name, and when the compiler sees your code it will assume that `Node` is a data member, not a nested type.